# Gluing plastic to glass

Tags: adhesive

What are some suitable adhesives for gluing plastic (in my case strips of Azek) to glass? Is contact cement good? Should I cement just the plastic or both sides (it would be hard to apply to the glass because of keeping it from spilling outside the perimeter of the plastic)?
Also, are there reliable temporary/removable caulking-like products that are gooey and although holding it together can later be scraped off?

[image: Azek is between the foam and the glass]
<sub>Azek is between the foam and the glass</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If both surfaces to be joined are fairly flat than contact cement will bond them together with a strong grip. Use the contact cement that isn't labled as "green" or "environmentally safe". Get the type with high VOC's it is stronger and will hold longer.

If any of the surfaces aren't flat you should use an adhesive that is thick or gel-like. I've had great performance from the adhesive labeled "Goop" or "Shoe-Goop". It is sold in a clear and black tone. It sets-up in 12 hours and full cures in 24 hours. I like that when cured it doesn't become solid or brittle, but still bonds with tremendous force and remains resilient. This is a very good adhesive for plastic to plastic as it will "weld" them together.

Also any type of construction adhesive, urethane caulking or hot glue will hold the pieces together, but not as strong as the first two mentioned.

And to use the contact cement (for the strongest bond) apply it to both surfaces in a light coating. You must than wait for the cement to "tack" or become "dull" in color before joining them together (be focused on their placement. Once joined it is very hard to remove).

Comment: How about Liquid Nails for the uneven scenario?

Comment: Also, check the last question I just added, please

Comment: Liquid Nails is a construction adhesive better suited for wood to wood.

Comment: If you use 100% silicone caulking the bond will be adequate and with a razor can be removed.